# How to configure different APIGateway endpoints for lambda versions $LATEST and live AutoPublishAlias

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm using [SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) with AutoPublishAlias [safe lambda deployments](https://awslabs.github.io/serverless-application-model/safe_lambda_deployments.html). However, in the Pretraffic hook, I'd like to run some initial validation tests by invoking the latest [unvalidated] lambda version through an AWS API Gateway endpoint that's different from the endpoint that points to stable lambda version.

In my case, it's quite challenging to call the lambda function directly by by-passing APIGateway in the pre-traffic hook because the lambda function includes whitelisting and other logic that requires values set by [API Gateway proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html). Ideally, I'd like to have 2 API gateway endpoints that always point to the live & latest versions of the lambda function as follows:

/api/resource -> lambdaFunction:live

/api/latest_resource -> lambdaFunction:$LATEST

This way, the pre-traffic hook can always use `/api/latest_resource` while customers use `/api/resource`. So far, I've not been able to figure out a way to configure this in SAM [AWS::Serverless::Function](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction) or [AWS::Severless::Api](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessapi). Does anyone have an example or idea of how to do this?

Comment: Generally the standard activity for this, is the pre traffic lambda invokes the new version of the lambda directly.  I dont understand why you need to go through APIGateway, pretraffic lambda bypasses this.  Please explain, I have implemented several use cases of it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the lambda function includes whitelisting logic and other code that makes use of values set by API Gateway. These things execute to ensure the caller has right permissions and logs some details about the request even before the request gets to the "main logic" of the lambda function. This means it I bypass api GW to invoke the lambda directly, the lambda throws errors before even getting to the main logic I need to validate in the pretraffic hook. I'm trying to find out an easy way to include APIGW without having to redesign the entire lambda function.

Comment: By the way, I've made some good progress by adding a new API gateway stage that always maps to lambdaFunction:$LATEST. This new stage is used by only the pre-traffic hook. Customers can't hit this stage because they access the API through a custom domain that's mapped to the default API gateway stage that points to lambdaFunction:live. I'll post the details once I've finished doing some more validation and code cleanup.